# Apple pay capability off but xcode still complains

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, applepay

I have two bundle ids `com.myapp` and `com.myapp.dev`

`com.myapp.dev` uses the Apple Pay capability and is properly configured and working, i can build and release normally.

However, `com.myapp` doesn't have the Apple Pay capability i.e it's off on the Capabilities section. When i am trying to build that one, i get an error that points out how my provisioning profile doesn't include the proper entitlements and so on.

Any clues as to why this might be happening? The Apple Pay capability is definitely off on `com.myapp`

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I also deleted derived data but no joy there either

Comment: So you have turned off the Apple Pay capability in the Xcode project's cpabailities? The entitlements must match between the Xcode project being built and the provisioning profiles entitlements  Can you show a screenshot of your Xcode capabilities settings?

Answer (score 0):

if you changed the bundle it during run of same app you should re configure provision profiles to match exactly the current app configurations , it's better to manually configure provision profiles for every change

Edit: clear derived data

Comment: i havent changed any bundle ids unfortunately.. they're supposed to be different so the clients can have both a dev and live version on their phones at the same time. one shouldnt interfere with the other and yet somehow xcode thinks com.myapp needs Apple Pay. The only thing i can think of is maybe that this happens because im using Apple Pay code conditionally in my source code?

Im really unsure as its the first time im implementing this capability but it shouldnt matter as long as i've shut it off..

Comment: yes, i just created one once more, it considers it to be valid as it should. Also the App Id com.myapp on the developer portal shows Apple Pay as disabled..

Comment: No joy with derived data deletion either. S.O automatically did this: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162096/discussion-between-george-avgoustis-and-sh-khan)

Answer (score 0):

Clearing derived data alone didnt work but by also restarting the system solved the issue. Some uncanny xcode bug i guess.